# Mobile broadband device heats up - is there anything to worry about?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I have recently bought a Reliance Netconnect mobile broadband device, and it remains in use all 24 hours of the day.

I have noticed that the device heats up after an hour or so of usage.

Is my continuous usage of the device likely to cause it any harm? Can it affect its functioning some way or lessen its life? Are there any cautions I could take in this regard, to ensure the proper functioning and long life for my mobile broadband device?

Answer (score 2):

It is totally normal for small devices to heat up a bit.

My Atheros PC-Slot WLAN Card heats up while in usage. My USB-Sticks heat up a good amount aswell. Chips are designed to work in room temperature environments, as long as you can touch the device and it does not smell funny, everything should be in order.

Strange cooling behavior could damage your device as well, most devices are designed to distribute the heat throughout itself (maybe even using the plug or casing to release some heat). Cooling in a not intended way can produce tension which will actually lower the lifetime.

again: chips are fine working with like 70°C (internally) or even higher. just do not cover the device (clothing) and ensure your computer is placed on top of a hard surface so the circulation below the device isn't hindered